# angularjs, java, 404, spark

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to learn more about creating SPA's using AngularJS and Java. I followed the tutorial [here](https://blog.openshift.com/developing-single-page-web-applications-using-java-8-spark-mongodb-and-angularjs/) and i managed to get it working except for one bug. When i create a new todo and then return to the todo list i get the following error.

> angular.js:8109 POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/todos 404 (Not Found)

The console output is as follows

```
HEJ ERROR
app.js:51 Error createTodo <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/v1/todos. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't it work after i added another todo?

Angular code

```
var app = angular.module('todoapp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
    }).when('/create', {
        templateUrl: 'views/create.html',
        controller: 'CreateCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })
});

app.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/v1/todos').success(function (data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        console.log('Error listctrl ' + data)
    })

    $scope.todoStatusChanged = function (todo) {
        console.log(todo);
        $http.put('/api/v1/todos/' + todo.id, todo).success(function (data) {
            console.log('status changed');
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            console.log('Error todostatuschanged' + data)
        })
    }
});

app.controller('CreateCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.todo = {
        done: false
    };

    $scope.createTodo = function () {
        console.log($scope.todo);
        $http.post('/api/v1/todos', $scope.todo, $location).success(function (data) {
            console.log("HEJ")
            $location.path('/');
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            console.log("HEJ ERROR")
            console.log('Error createTodo ' + data)
        })
    }
});
```

Java Code:

```
import static spark.Spark.get;
import static spark.Spark.post;
import static spark.Spark.put;

public class TodoResource {

    private static final String API_CONTEXT = "/api/v1";

    private final TodoService todoService;

    public TodoResource(TodoService todoService) {
        this.todoService = todoService;
        setupEndpoints();
    }

    private void setupEndpoints() {
        post(API_CONTEXT + "/todos", "application/json", (request, response) -> {
            todoService.createNewTodo(request.body());
            response.status(201);
            return response;
        }, new JsonTransformer());

        get(API_CONTEXT + "/todos/:id", "application/json", (request, response)

                -> todoService.find(request.params(":id")), new JsonTransformer());

        get(API_CONTEXT + "/todos", "application/json", (request, response)

                -> todoService.findALL(), new JsonTransformer());

        put(API_CONTEXT + "/todos/:id", "application/json", (request, response)

                -> todoService.update(request.params(":id"), request.body()), new JsonTransformer());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I removed the "new JsonTransformer()" from the first endpoint.

I don't know why it worked but it did.